# My laptop not comes on the network when connected to cisco 2951 routing port, so it does not ping

Tags: cisco, routing, router, network

I have assigned 192.168.1.2/24 IP to laptop with 192.168.1.1 gateway. This gateway is actually the IP address of the Cisco 2951 router port. But my laptop doesn't come in the network that's why it doesn't ping the router port.

The status of the laptop and router port is up.

I have configured the same scenario on the other port of the Cisco 2951 router but there is no issue with it.

Comment: I think you need to provide relevant parts of the cisco configuration to enable us to suggest solutions to your issue. It could be that the port you are connected to on the switch is not in the same vlan as the vlan with the default gw?

Comment: I am not connecting on switch. I am directly connecting router port to laptop and it works on one port but not on the other port.

Answer (score 1):

Router ports require configuration. Unless they are put in the same switching group, each port is a separate L3 interface, connecting to a separate (possibly unconfigured) subnet on the router.

You cannot use router ports at random like you can use switch ports.

Comment: I am not using any switch b/w router and laptop and it is working on the other port without any special configuration.

Comment: "The other port" may be in a switching group. You need to check the router's configuration for what it does and configure it to add what it doesn't. You can add the config to your question for us to review (remove public IP addresses, user accounts, passwords, ... first).

Comment: Zac, I have already added configuration in details. I used private Ip address scheme. It's a new router so there is no previous configuration on this port.

Comment: I was referring to the output of `show running-config`. Additionally, we need to know which ports "the one" and "the other" are.